# Mock enhanced DynamoDbTable CRUD operations

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

How to mock software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbTable.getItem?

So far I have tried the below, which is throwing NullPointerException from inside the SDK.
Any idea how to mock the table CRUD operations?

```
  @Mock private DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhdynamodb;
  @Mock private DynamoDbClient dynamodb;
  @Mock private DynamoDbTable<EventRecord> dyamodbTable;
  @Mock private SecurityContext securityContext;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    when(securityContext.getUserPrincipal()).thenReturn(principal);
    enhdynamodb = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder().dynamoDbClient(dynamodb).build();
    dyamodbTable = enhdynamodb.table(TABLE_NAME, TableSchema.fromBean(EventRecord.class));
    service = new EventsService(tokenSerializer, enhdynamodb, configProvider, clock);
    service.setSecurityContext(securityContext);
  }


  @Test
  public void getEvent_null_notFound() {
    String userId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String eventId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    GetItemResponse response = GetItemResponse.builder().build();
    EventRecord event = null;
    when(principal.getName()).thenReturn(userId);
    when(dyamodbTable.getItem(any(GetItemEnhancedRequest.class))).thenReturn(event);   
    assertThatThrownBy(() -> service.getEvent(eventId)).isInstanceOf(NotFoundApiException.class);
  }


  public Event getEvent(String eventId) {
    log.info("Getting event {}", eventId);
    EventRecord eventRecord = loadEvent(eventId);
    return modelMapper.map(eventRecord, Event.class);
  }

  private EventRecord loadEvent(final String eventId) {    
    String userId = securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName();
    EventRecord event =
        getTable()
            .getItem(
                GetItemEnhancedRequest.builder()
                    .consistentRead(Boolean.TRUE)
                    .key(k -> k.partitionValue(userId).sortValue(eventId).build())
                    .build());

    if (event == null) {
      throw new NotFoundApiException(
          new NotFoundException()
              .errorCode("EventNotFound")
              .message(String.format("Event %s can not be found.", eventId)));
    }
    return event;
  }

  private DynamoDbTable<EventRecord> getTable() {
      return dynamodb.table(tableName, TableSchema.fromBean(EventRecord.class));
  }
```

Comment: Just tried it it does not throw any exceptions, could share more info like how you are mocking the ´dyamodbTable´?

Comment: I have updated the question with mock variables  details. Seems its better to mock DynamoDbClient than  DynamoDbEnhancedClient even when the implementation using DynamoDbEnhancedClient+enhanced.DyanamoDbTable. Can you share how you did the mock test for getItem and query?

Comment: Added the example, also recommended different way of testing your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it like this and it does not throw exceptions.

```
  @Test
  public void getEvent_null_notFound() {
    String userId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String eventId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    DynamoDbTable dynamoDbTable = mock(DynamoDbTable.class);

    EventRecord  event = null;
    when(dynamoDbTable.getItem(any(GetItemEnhancedRequest.class))).thenReturn(event);

    assertEquals(event, dynamoDbTable.getItem(event));
  }
```

Note that I mocking `DynamoDbTable` instead of `DynamoDbEnhancedClient`.

Mocking calls to the client and doing unit test on your own code is of course a good idea but I highly recommend using the local dynamodb library if you want to do an actual DyanmoDb calls with a local DB.

Here is full [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html). If you use this library in your unit tests you dont need to mock the calls.